# Ideal schema design for privacy settings in MongoDB and Meteor

Tags: python, mongodb, meteor

I have a set of documents that can have various READ privacy settings around them:

1. They can be completed public (any registered user) can view them
2. They can be viewable only by people following you (this "Followers"
   array is stored in each User's document)
3. They can be private to the person who published the document as well.
4. They can have custom privacy which allows you to name individual users who can view the document. In addition, you can allow groups of users to also view the document (e.g. there could be a group called "Sample Group" which has 20 users in it. You could allow said group to view the tile.)

I am lost as to how to implement a schema for this efficiently in MongoDB and would love some insight into best practices for implementing this schema.

Comment: are these permissions just for READ operation - ie: you are allowing the members in the groups to just READ the document, not edit it? - Or, like google docs, you can set some users to read, some to edit etc...

Answer (score 0):

We've done several projects with multiple access levels and mongoose, and this has been our favorite method so far:

```
var ACCESS_MODES = 'public followers private explicit'.split(' ');

var projectSchema = new Schema({
  access: { type: String, enum: ACCESS_MODES, required: true, default: 'public' },
  owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

We then usually implement some custom access methods on the schema, eg:

```
projectSchema.statics.getByIdFor = function(user, id, done) {
  this.findOne({ _id: id }).populate('owner').exec(onFound);
  function onFound(err, project) {
    // now check 'user' against the project's access method:
    if (project.access === 'public') return done(undefined, project);
    if (project.access === 'private') {
       // ...etc, handle the logic for access at different levels
    }
    // finally, they didn't get access
    done(new Error('no permission to access this project'));
  }
};
```

So you can now do something like this and know that it's safe:

`ProjectModel.findByIdFor(loggedinUser, req.params.projectId, onFound);`

To find all the projects a user has access to:

```
projectSchema.statics.getForUser = function(user, done) {
  var accessible = [];
  this.find({ access: 'public' }).exec(onPublic);
  this.find({ access: 'followers' }).populate('owner').exec(onFollowers);
  this.find({ access: 'private', owner: user }).exec(onPrivate);
  this.find({ access: 'explicit' }).populate('owner').exec(onExplicit);
  // add onPublic/Followers/Private/Explicit to accessible where user is in the correct list
};
```

Comment: The trouble here is that every time a user get's a new follower, each of the documents followers collection will need to be updated...

Comment: Didn't you say that this happens already? "They can be viewable only by people following you (this "Followers" array is stored in each User's document)" - OP

Comment: Oh I see what you mean - this is the project schema and the followers are stored on the user. That's easy enough, 1s...

Comment: Now, when you check the access level, you `populate()` the owner of the project to check access levels.

Comment: See my answer. one of the big problems will be a function to get a list of documents each user can view. For example, in Google Docs, you have a list of all the documents you either created, or are shared with you etc.... I've used pseudo code in my answer since we're not sure what driver / platform he's using

Comment: just gave a quick example of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not specified a driver you're using (although tagged Javascript, so perhaps you're using mongoose?) I'll try and answer this using pseudo code / structures.

Your `document` collection I think could look something like this:

```
{
    _id,
    title,

    owner, //ref to User collection?

    access,  //'public', 'followers' etc...

    permissions[] 
}
```

`Permission` could look something like:

```
{
    // one or the other
    user_id 
    group_id
}
```

Now, the tricky part is producing a list of documents viewable for a given user.
To approach this

```
function findDocumentsViewableByUser(userID){

    var followedBy = //populate a list of userIDs that FOLLOW the passed in userID

    var groupIDs = //populate a list of groupIDs this user is a member of

    // all documents where access = 'public'

    // all documents where access = 'followers' AND owner_id is in followedBy

    // all documents where access = 'custom' 
    // and permissions.user_id = userID OR groupIDs contains permissions.groupID
}
```

Depending on the structure of your User and Group type documents, the queries in the above findDocumentsViewableByUser will be significantly reduced.
You would probably be best of using the Aggregation Framework for this also.

Comment: This is for implementation in Meteor.